# Why does a single thread exception crash entire program (how to prevent this?)

Tags: multithreading, winapi, exception, crash

If I run, for example,

```
int x = *(0x00000);
```

The program crashes. But why does the whole program crash instead of that single thread? I created multiple threads that just sleep continuously to test this out. Is there any way to make only the current thread exit, not the whole program (on windows using winapi)?

Thanks.

Comment: That is I would say in the *definition* of threads. Consider some multi-process approach instead. And POSIX threads behave likewise w.r.t. [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)s...

Comment: I don't know Windows at all. There could be a way to catch such a mess, but it would be a difficult and brittle way.

Comment: Sounds like you are throwing the exception in the *main* thread causing your `main()`/`WinMain()` to exit. That would certainly take out your process. Throwing an exception in a *worker* thread won't do that.

Comment: this is by design. if exist unhandled (by debugger and process) exception - system terminate process. of course os can do and another choise - terminate only current thread, instead process. but after this (unhandled exception and thread terminate) almost always process will be in corrupted state and new exceptions will be..

Comment: Thanks. Can you make these an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But why does the whole program crash instead of that single thread?

This is by design. If nobody (not the debugger if attached and not the process itself) handles the user mode exception, the system terminates the process, and this is logical.

All resources are shared per process, not per thread. After an unhandled exception happens the process is probably in an unstable/corrupted state. New exceptions will occur or the other threads might hang.

The thread could for example own some critical section or another resource at the time of the exception. If the thread terminates at this point the resource will be always in use by the crashed thread. When another thread tries to enter this "critical section" (in a broad sense) it hangs forever. (For example a heap critical section).

So better just terminate the process instead of getting new exceptions and undefined behavior in the process.

By the same line of reasoning, if an unhandled exception was in kernel mode the system terminates itself and tries to create a BSOD. Because after an unhandled exception in the kernel, all systems are in an unstable state and simply terminating the buggy thread is not a solution.

> Is there any way to make only the current thread exit, not the whole
> program (on windows using winapi)?

Formally yes, it's easy, you can set [`UnhandledExceptionFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-unhandledexceptionfilter)  with the [`SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-setunhandledexceptionfilter) function and inside [`UnhandledExceptionFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-unhandledexceptionfilter) simply call [`TerminateThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminatethread) for the current thread ( [`GetCurrentThread()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentthread) ) because

> The exception handler specified by lpTopLevelExceptionFilter is
> executed in the context of the thread that caused the fault.

Also note that this callback is called only if the process is not being debugged.

However, terminating the thread is not a proper solution. The solution is that there must not be exceptions in your process or you need to handle it. If you can not the process must end.